# How to clean a computer motherboard?

Tags: cleaning, hardware

I was wondering how to clean a computer motherboard knowing that using conventional cleaning products is obviously prohibited.

What is the most effective and least dangerous way to remove dust?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use compressed air from a can.  Do not use air from an industrial or an electric pump (yes, people have done this.)  Make sure that the can is upright when you spray, or it might come out too cold.

An even better solution is to use pressurized electronic contact cleaner.  Make sure you use electronics contact cleaner, which is almost pure alcohol.  Do not use any other kind of alcohol, because the water content will be too high, and you'll ruin your electronics.

Comment: Thank you for your answer ! Just a question on my side, what is the difference between an *compressed air from a can* and *pressurized electronic contact cleaner* ?

Comment: @Ced pressurized electronic contact cleaner contains alcohol, and eliminates the risk of a static charge coming from the can.  The alcohol also acts as a desiccant, in case ther's humidity, and also, there is a chance that the compressed air might contain moisture, which is the enemy of electronics.

Answer (score 3):

Using a can of compressed air spray the surface of the motherboard from 6 inches away.